# My first attempt at a basic java applet failed. i cant figure out why the rectangle does not move

Tags: java, applet

```
public class Basics extends Applet{

int x = 0;

int y = 0;

    public void init(){
        setSize(500,500);
    }

    public void start(){
        Thread a = new Thread();
        a.start();
    }

    public void run(){
        while(true){
            x = 100;
            y = 100;                
            repaint();
            try{
                Thread.sleep(18);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e){}
        }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(this.x,this.y,25,25);
    }

}
```

Shouldnt incrementing x and y and then repainting allow the square to move

Comment: If you want to move the rectangle you have to increment your x and y

Comment: You never increment your `x` and `y` inside the loop.

Answer (score 6):

You should increment your x and y value, now you are only assigning values to it. Change it like this:

```
public void run(){
        while(true){
            x += 100;
            y += 100;                
            repaint();
            try{
                Thread.sleep(18);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e){}
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your run method, you;re not incremening X and Y, you're setting them.

Try doing

```
x += 100;
y += 100;
```

I would use smaller values, though, start with 1.